# How to rearrange a WinForms Controls during runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project I wanted to order controls at run-time, like in `DataGridView` how we'll use display-index to order fields in the grid.

In design level I added 3 `TextBox`s and 1 `ComboBox` next to each other & in run time i wanted to order them, for example, first 2 `TextBox`s should show, then the `ComboBox` and then the other `TextBox`.

Is it possible to rearrange the controls in run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.forms.Control.aspx) in Windows Forms has a [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) property. You can easily change the location of the control by changing this property:

```
textBox1.Location = new Point(10, 50); // Puts the TextBox at coordinates (10,50)
```

The coordinates are relative to upper-left corner of the control container (the form itself for example).

In your case, you can easily arrange the controls like this:

```
Control[] controls = new Control[] { textBox1, textBox2, comboBox3, textBox3 }; // These are your controls
int left = 20, top = 50; // or any other value
foreach (c in controls)
{
    c.Location = new Point(left, top);
    left += c.Width + 10; // space 10 pixels between controls
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to control the visibility of the controls. sounds like he is wanting to organize a 3 step wizard or something. Yes its possible to manipulate all the properties of the controls - you need to be a bit clearer about exactly what you want to accomplish though. Or maybe that's exactly what hes looking for - not sure I can tell :)

Comment: Columns in `DataGridView` have a `DisplayIndex` property, that lets them change their positions in the grid. I guess the OP needs somethings similar to this, and I think I gave him the hint.